Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'vec' in pubkey TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'vec' in pubkey
I am getting this error while trying to interacting with the solana program from react front-end :-
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useAnchorWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { Connection, PublicKey, SystemProgram, Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Program, AnchorProvider } from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { getAssociatedTokenAddressSync } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import {
    WalletMultiButton,
    WalletDisconnectButton,
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import idl from '../idl.json';
import { Container, ButtonGroup, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import MintCollection from './Collection';

require('@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css');

const ProgramContext = createContext(null);

const programID = new PublicKey(idl.metadata.address);
const network = 'https://api.devnet.solana.com/';
const opts = { preflightCommitment: 'processed' };

const Wallet = () => {
    const wallet = useAnchorWallet();
    const { connected } = useWallet();
    console.log(connected);
    const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null);
    const [program, setProgram] = useState(null);
    const [collectionName, setCollectionName] = useState('');
    const [collectionSymbol, setCollectionSymbol] = useState('');
    const [collectionURI, setCollectionURI] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const getProvider = () => {
        if (!wallet) return null;
        const connection = new Connection(network, opts.preflightCommitment);
        return new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, opts.preflightCommitment);
    };

    // setProvider(getProvider);

    const mintCollection = async () => {
        setError('');
        if (!connected) {
            setError('Wallet is not connected.');
            return;
        }
        const provider = getProvider();
        if (!provider) {
            setError('Provider is not available.');
            return;
        }
        const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);
        console.log(program);
        setProgram(program);
        try {
            const collectionMintAccount = Keypair.generate();

            const collectionAssociatedTokenAccount =
                getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
                    [
                        collectionMintAccount.publicKey.toBuffer(),
                        provider.wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(),
                    ],
                    program.programId
                );

            program.methods.mintCollection(
                collectionName,
                collectionSymbol,
                collectionURI,
                {
                    accounts: {
                        payer: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                        collectionMintAccount: collectionMintAccount.publicKey,
                        collectionAssociatedTokenAccount:
                            collectionAssociatedTokenAccount[0],
                    },
                    signers: [collectionMintAccount],
                }
            );

            // setCollectionAddress(collectionMintAccount.publicKey.toString());
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error minting collection:', error);
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <>
            <Container className="d-flex justify-content-center my-3">
                <ButtonGroup>
                    <div className="me-2">
                        <WalletMultiButton />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <WalletDisconnectButton />
                    </div>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </Container>
            {/* <MintCollection program={program} /> */}
            <h2>Mint Collection</h2>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group controlId="collectionName">
                    <Form.Label>Collection Name</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter collection name"
                        value={collectionName}
                        onChange={(e) => setCollectionName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="collectionSymbol">
                    <Form.Label>Collection Symbol</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter collection symbol"
                        value={collectionSymbol}
                        onChange={(e) => setCollectionSymbol(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="collectionURI">
                    <Form.Label>Collection URI</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter collection URI"
                        value={collectionURI}
                        onChange={(e) => setCollectionURI(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Button variant="primary" onClick={mintCollection}>
                    Mint Collection
                </Button>
            </Form>

            {/* {collectionAddress && (
                <div>
                    <h3>Collection Minted!</h3>
                    <p>Collection Address: {collectionAddress}</p>
                </div>
            )} */}
        </>
    );
};

export default Wallet;


The erroring code with vec doesn't appear in your code, so you'll need to provide more info

Same error: /home/manoguar/dragoncorp/solana-dao/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/coder/borsh/idl.js:92 if ("vec" in field.type) { ^ TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'vec' in pubkey at IdlCoder.fieldLayout (/home/manoguar/dragoncorp/solana-dao/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/coder/borsh/idl.js:92:27) at /home/manoguar/dragoncorp/solana-dao/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/coder/borsh/instruction.js:109:42 at Array.map () at /home/manoguar/dragoncorp/solana-dao/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/coder/borsh/instruction.js:10
